# How to make some div elements move right and left like slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Here are my some divs( which have col-md-2 col-sm-4 classes) it shows some icons, I would like to these icons move right and left like a slider in mobile devices

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row social">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
      <a href="#" class="link cat" target="_parent" style="margin-right: 0px;"> 
        <img class="categ" src="img/off-road.png" />
      </a>
      <div>yiiiii</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
      <a href="#" class="link cat" target="_parent">
        <img class="categ" src="img/sea.png" />
      </a>
      <div>miiii</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
      <a href="#" class="link cat" target="_parent">
        <img class="categ" src="img/summer.png" />
      </a>
      <div>biiiiii</div>
    </div>                                           
  </div>
</div>
```

I've found the solution I use slick sliders ---> http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
and also it explains the usage of it
my code :

```
          <div class="container">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row social">
                      <div class="slider-services ">
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                              <a href="#" class="link cat" target="_parent" style="margin-right: 0px;"><img class="categ" src="img/off-road.png" /></a>
                              <div>iiii</div>

                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                              <a href="#" class="link cat" target="_parent"><img class="categ" src="img/sea.png" /></a>
                              <div>miii</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                              <a href="#" class="link cat" target="_parent"><img class="categ" src="img/summer.png" /></a>
                              <div>biii</div>
                          </div>
                    
                      </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>

              <script>
                     $(document).ready(function (){
                  $('.slider-services').slick({
                      dots: true,
                      infinite: true,
                      speed: 300,
                      slidesToShow: 1,
                      centerMode: true,
                      variableWidth: true
                  });
                 
         
                           });
                      </script>
```

Comment: Add the JavaScript code you have made.

Comment: Have you tried [Bootstrap carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) ?